# What is the 4-digit octal Unix file permission system?

Tags: php, linux, file, security, system

3-digit:

644
 (user group other)
4-digit:

4750 
 (??? user group other)
What is the first octal digit for in 4-digit octal Unix file permission notation?

Comment: See also [whats the difference between chmod 777 and chmod 7777](//superuser.com/q/592309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called sticky bit in linux.
you can read it detaily from this link: https://www.linuxnix.com/sticky-bit-set-linux/